# Is there a source for a man not addressing his wife by her first name?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, names, marriage, chareidim-ultraorthodox

I know a man who when addressing his wife calls her [for example] Mrs Doe as opposed to 'Jane' or 'Honey' [he does this when he is home too]. This person is very religious and what some might call 'Chareidi', I was wondering if it had anything to do with religion or if maybe it's just a 'thing'.

Comment: There's a tradition to not call your mother by her name out of respect, but this is the first I've heard for a wife.

Comment: I observed that R. Berish Shapiro, the Naroler Rav of Brooklyn (now, I guess, **the** Naroler Rav, since his father passed away several years ago), never called his wife by her first name in my hearing. But I have no reason to think he avoided doing so in private. Note also that quite a few religious-right publications (or pieces in them) have their authorship attributed to a first initial and a last name.

Comment: http://www.jokes4us.com/kiddiejokes/oldcouplejoke.html

Comment: I know a guy who calls his wife "Mommy." I think he does this even when his kids aren't around. Also his kids are grown-up.

Comment: @Daniel We never met. But besides having the same 1st name, it's a bit too co-incidental that you mention something that I do often. I usually call my wife "Mom". Besides out of respect and admiration to her "role", I developed it as a habit myself as I didn't want to confuse my kids and have them accidentally call their mother by her 1st name. My wife also calls me "Abba". So, I think the idea goes for wives not using their husbands' first names. It's a good practice, I think.

Answer (score 3):

[נטעי גבריאל, in הלכות נשואין, volume 2, chapter 118, section 8, footnote 11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46546&pgnum=296), cites [the מהרי״ל‬](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33228&pgnum=17) ([biographical information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_ben_Moshe_Levi_Moelin)):

> שכשהיה קורא לאשתו אמר בלשון‬ ‫אשכנז הער״ט איר ניט כדרך העולם שהזיווגים אין מזכירין שמותיהן‬ ‫כשקורין זה את זו או זו את זה‬

Or, in my own translation with help from [Gershon Gold](/a/18675):

> When he would call his wife, he'd say in German<sup>[1]</sup> "Did you not hear", in accordance with the way the world acts, that couples calling one another don't mention one another's names.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> actually some dialect of what we now call [Early New High German](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_German), I suppose

Comment: הער״ט איר ניט [herrt irr nitt] is normal Yiddish today, although נישט [nisht] is supplanting ניט [nitt] west of the Atlantic.

Comment: Maharil had an interesting relationship with that wife. They were both widowers. He didn't live at home, he lived next door in the yeshiva. He never benefited from her choosing to rather live off communal money. And if I recall correctly when he referred to her, he called her his 'house wife'.

Answer (score 1):

In Mas. Shabbos on [daf 118b](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00844.html#HtmpReportNum0233_L2) it says:  Reb Yossi never called his wife "wife". He called her "my house". From this gemora I think it's the minhag not to call the wife by her name.

> אמר רבי יוסי: מימי לא קריתי לאשתי *אשתי* ולשורי *שורי* אלא לאשתי *ביתי* ולשורי *שדי*

Comment: So why call her _Mrs. Doe_ instead of _My House_? (Rashi: אשתי ביתי. שהיא עיקר של בית)

Comment: doesnt say why he did this or whether it is recommended for others

Comment: I don't see how this Gemara is at all related to not calling your wife by her first name. And certainly doesn't directly relate to what you call her in private.

Comment: @Danny if they would've had last names, Reb Yosi might have called her by that title. IIRC Maharil called his wife 'my house wife'.

Comment: @user6591 - did you see the Rashi I quoted? She was called _My Home_ as she's the _main part_ of the  home. So unless your home has a name... Mrs. Galore Masion....

Comment: You can deduce that, why does he have to say my house in the beginning call her by her name. Why did the gemora write this piece in the first place?

Comment: @Danny I've seen it. the field was called the ox etc. But as Rashi in gitten points out, she took care of all the house work. The term Mrs. might imply that as well.

Comment: @Nachmen, do you have a source that says to read the gemarah as you're interpreting it?

Comment: I understood it to mean that that whenever referring to his wife he would say 'my house'

Comment: If you read what I wrote in the beginning this could be the root.

Comment: Among some of the people I deal with, it is the norm to refer to one's wife as "mayn shtib" (Yid. "my house") when speaking to others, and to call her "mamme" ("mom") when speaking to her. Some even go as far as to speak to their wife in 3rd person: "Efsher mamme vill..." ("Maybe mom wants...") This is not to make the children use the right form, as they say "mammi" ("mommy") instead (usually in 3rd person).